# How do I write an object to a file that already exists?

Tags: java, file, input, output

I'm having a problem with an assignment from school. I'm meant to output an arraylist of objects to a file, which I can do. But I'm supposed to check if the file exists, and if it does, then to output to that file, and not create a new one.

I've tried putting the FileOutputStream declaration outside of my if statement, but then the file will always exist.

I've also tried creating a new ObjectOutputStream in my first half of the if statement, but I get an IOException about the headers.

How do I write the objects (of class Employee) to a file that already exists?

```
    public void saveEmployeesToFile() {
          try {
        File employeeFile = new File("CurrentEmployees.emp");

        if (employeeFile.exists()) {

            System.out.println("File already exists");

        } else {
            FileOutputStream employeeFileObject = new FileOutputStream(employeeFile);
            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(employeeFileObject);

            for (Employee thisEmp : getEmployees()) {
                output.writeObject(thisEmp);
            }
            System.out.println("Employees successfully saved to new file");
            employeeFileObject.close();
            output.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Error initializing stream");
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the newer NIO package.

Your question is essentially, "how do I create a `FileOuputStream` for a file that already exists?"

```
Path employeeFilePath = Paths.get(employeeFile.toURI());
FileOutputStream employeeFileObject;
if (employeeFile.exists()) {
    employeeFileObject = Files.newOutputStream(employeeFilePath, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
} 
else {
    employeeFileObject = Files.newOutputStream(employeeFilePath, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
}

// Proceed to write data
```

Comment: `new FileOutputStream(employeeFile, true)` does the same as these eight lines, and it still won't work, as you can't append to `ObjectOutputStreams` without special measures.